# Excel 2010 Lookup and Offset

Tags: excel, offset, lookup

Sorry this is a basic question but will try to explain clearly.
I have two worksheets. One a summary and the other that holds the raw data. In the summary tab in cell A1 I have a drop down with each day dd/mm/yyyy.
What I want to do is to find the same date in the raw data table and then look down a set amount of columns and then look across a set about of rows and return that as my value in the summary sheet. 
Been trying but can only get to look down or across a column or row and not both.
I think I didn't get enough sleep last night!
Thanks in advance for any help at all.

Comment: I'm just hitting the hay myself but look at examples of `range activecell.column .select` or  `range activecell.row .select`. I came across something similar in a script today using these

Comment: It would be good if you could give a small example data set, as I'm a bit confused as to what you mean about looking across rows and columns.

Comment: @Clusks I can't attach anything at the moment but will try to explain

Comment: @Clusks in the raw data sheet across row 1 is dates. Each date has three columns of data so A1 has a date and then in columns a,b and c are columns of different data eg Hit, Missed and Total. The rows then have different work items eg received, despatched etc that have been hit or missed. This then goes on for each day for the remainder of the financial year so the next days date will be in e1, the next i1.

Comment: @Clusks So what I want to do in the summary sheet is if the date in the summary matches the date in the raw data sheet match then look down a certain amount of rows to find the work item I wish to report on and then across say 1 column to report how many missed target. Not sure if I've explained that well or not!

Answer (score 0):

Without an exact example to apply this to, I'm guessing what you want is [offset match match](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-offset-match-match/).

As per the formula on the link, you want:

```
= OFFSET ( starting point , MATCH ( vertical lookup value,  left hand lookup column excluding starting point , 0 ) , MATCH ( horizontal lookup value , top header row excluding starting point , 0 ) )
```

So, if I'm understanding correctly, you have a dataset that looks a bit like this:

[image: Example data set]

Below the data I have example of items you want to find. This probably isn't the cleanest way to do this, but say you want the "hit" column for Operation 2 on 03/07/1989, then it would be:

```
=OFFSET(A1,MATCH(A10,A1:A5,0)-1,MATCH(A9,A1:H1,0))
```

This will return "0.81544".

To get the right data, you'll need to mess about with the - and + at the match formulas, and without seeing your data set it's hard to get you exact examples, I hope it helps though! I had to modify it slightly due to the fact I believe that your top row will include the dates as well as the column headings for each. Going through the linked guide should help you plenty to tailor it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help, especially as having to use a crystal ball the guess what I was waffling on about. As suggested I've messed around with the + and - to tailor to my needs and it works perfect. Thanks again for your help